# How can I create a specific print fn in Python that prints the output to tkinter GUI instead of terminal?

Tags: python, numpy, user-interface, tensorflow, keras

I have the following part of code in Python:

```
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train_onehot, batch_size=b_size, epochs=epoch, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test_onehot)

print("score: ",score[0])
print("accuracy: ",score[1])

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
failed_pred = np.where((np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1) != 
np.argmax(y_test_onehot, axis=1)))
print("failed_pred")

x_test_prim = x_test[index]
print("x_test_prim.shape: ",x_test_prim.shape)

img_usable = np.expand_dims(x_test_prim, axis=0)
img_to_show = np.reshape(x_test_prim, (28,28))
plt.imshow(img_to_show)
print(img_usable.shape)
pred_prim = model.predict_classes(img_usable)
print("The prediction: ",pred_prim)
print("The reality: ",y_test[index])
```

How do I print every single print fn in tkinter GUI? 
Is there a way to call this fn in future programs built from scratch?

Comment: ... hi Claudiu... welcome to SO. Good to see you got the hang of the use with "*" , etc... Could you please trim-down your question code to normal mode. All your use-full comments require inline "#" for python and not like what you just did. It now looks like a zebra... Wanna get hunted by down-votes and end-up in triage review? (a.k.a. purgatory for dubious questions)!

Comment: While it is generally better to post code than not to, you should always ask yourself if the code you are posing is in any way relevant to the question.

Comment: @ZF007, I have to say that I laughed. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I tried to show the print statements I referred to and highlight the fact that I want to run this code in GUI. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Where is your tkinter code? What research have you done? This looks like a request for a tutorial or free code. Both are off topic.